# configure CXXFLAGS refuses to accept more than one include path

Tags: gcc, configure, autotools, automake

I am trying to build a project that requires two include paths.
My command is:

```
 ./autogen.sh --prefix /usr/ --libdir /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ CXXFLAGS="-I${TensorflowPath} -I${TensorflowPath}/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include" --enable-tflite
```

and I have set TensorflowPath to the correct path for my tensorflow source directory.

but the error I get is:

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-I/home/aaron/src/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include'
```

This is really maddening! The second or third option is always erroring out. Please advise !!

Comment: This looks like someone has forgotten necessary quotes in the `autogen.sh` script or perhaps in the project's `configure` script (via `configure.ac`).  That is, it is specific to the project you are trying to build.  We haven't enough information to identify the problem more precisely, but you could try bypassing `autogen.sh` and running `configure` directly (and then `make` and so on).

Comment: Many `autogen.sh` scripts calling `configure` are broken, and many can and should be replaced by a call to `autoreconf`. My general recommendation is to call those scripts (if they actually do more than `autoreconf` does) as `autogen.sh --help` to prevent the called configure from actually doing anything. Then you can call `configure` with all your command line arguments without worrying about `autogen.sh` misquoting the arguments you passed.

Comment: @ndim - totally agree. Unless there's a *very* good reason that `autoreconf -fvi` can't regenerate the build system, it's often a smell in the use of the autotools.

Answer (score 2):

This `autogen.sh` script appears to be broken both conceptually by unifying two very distinct steps (generating `configure` with its related files and running `configure`) into one without good reason, and by the actual implementation of that broken concept using a broken way of passing command line arguments to the child `configure` process.

If you can replace the call to `autogen.sh` with a call to `autoreconf -vis .`, just do that and ignore the broken `autogen.sh`:

```
autoreconf -vis .
./configure CXXFLAGS="-Ifoo -Ibar" --prefix=/what/ever --and-so-on
make
make install
```

If you absolutely need to use that `autogen.sh` script and cannot just replace it with a call to `autoreconf -vis .`, call `autogen.sh` with the single parameter `--help` to prevent it from running `configure` with any consequences.

The single `--help` argument contains no spaces and thus even an `autogen.sh` script with shell quoting bugs should pass it on correctly to `configure`. Now `autogen.sh` should do its buildsystem setup first, and then run `configure --help` which does nothing but print a bunch of messages to the console.

Then you can run your actual `configure` command with the correct parameters afterwards:

```
./autogen.sh --help
./configure CXXFLAGS="-Ifoo -Ibar" --prefix=/what/ever --and-so-on
make
make install
```